# List all bosses who have at least 3 staff members

Tags: sql, group-by, having

How can I query the table below to get the names of all bosses (ie boss_id = staff_id)
who have at least 3 staff? Do I use `having`, `group by`, ...?

```
    CREATE TABLE STAFF (STAFF_ID                    CHAR(3),
                        STAFF_NAME              CHAR(20),
                        GENDER                  CHAR(6),
                        DEPARTMENT              CHAR(20),
                        BOSS_ID                 CHAR(3)
                        SALARY                  NUMBER(8,2))
```

Thanks!

Comment: Smells like homework to me...

Comment: @Bridge: [Not the first one too...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391356/sql-find-average-salary-for-each-department-with-more-than-five-members)

Comment: Have you tried *anything* at all?

Comment: of course i'm trying, i'm just not yet familiar with 'group by', 'having' function..

Comment: @user1225281 It's essentially a where clause, but for aggregate functions used with grouping. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx for an example.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using `COUNT(*)>3` because I assume, that you mean 3 staff except the boss himself.

```
SELECT a.staff_name
FROM staff a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT boss_id,COUNT(*) AS cnt_staff FROM staff GROUP BY boss_id HAVING COUNT(*)>3
) b ON a.boss_id=b.boss_id
WHERE a.staff_id=a.boss_id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select boss_id, staff_name 
from staff 
group by boss_id, staff_name 
having count(staff_id)>=3
```

Comment: its at position 2 in your result set. if you just want the staff_name, just leave out the boss_id in the select and the group by. then the staff_name is your only result.

Comment: but if in the case where i look for the name of the boss, can i do : select STAFF_ID from staff where STAFF_ID = BOSS_ID group by BOSS_ID having count(STAFF_ID)>=3

Comment: @user1225281 no, that's not possible

Answer (score 1):

```
select S.Boss_ID, X.STAFF_NAME
from STAFF S cross apply (Select staff_name from STAFF S2 where S2.staff_id=S.boss_ID) X
group by S.Boss_ID, X.STAFF_NAME
having count(*)>=3
```